# What happens if you try to run code faster than your Arduino can handle?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, arduino-uno

I've been trying to program my Arduino to spin a BLDC motor.

When I have this code running the BLDC motor runs perfectly every time. It also makes the motor rotate pretty fast:

```
// This function checks for pin Interrupts with Hall Effect Sensors (pins 2, 3, 4). Once an interrupt is detected I switch to the next pair of MOSFETs
// * Note * digital pins 13,12, and 8 are P-CH MOSFETs while digital pins 11,10,9 are N-CH MOSFETs.
ISR(PCINT2_vect) {
  switch(PIND) {
    case 231:
    // Turns ON MOSFETs from pins 11 & 8
    PORTB = B11110000;
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    break;

    case 239:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 11 & 12
    PORTB = B11100001;
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    break;

    case 235:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 9 & 12
    PORTB = B11100001;
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    break;

    case 251:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 9 & 13
    PORTB = B11010001;
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    break;

    case 243:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 10 & 13
    PORTB = B11010001;
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    break;

    case 247:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 10 & 8
    PORTB = B11110000;
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    break;
  }
}
```

When I run this code the BLDC motor no longer works and it won't rotate at all:

```
// This function checks for pin Interrupts with Hall Effect Sensors (pins 2, 3, 4). Once an interrupt is detected I switch to the next pair of MOSFETs
// * Note * digital pins 13,12, and 8 are P-CH MOSFETs while digital pins 11,10,9 are N-CH MOSFETs.
int value = 255;

ISR(PCINT2_vect) {
 switch(PIND) {
  case 231:
  // Turn on MOSFETs from pins 11 & 8
  PORTB = B11110000;
  analogWrite(11, value);
  break;

  case 239:
  // Turn on MOSFETs from pins 11 & 12
  PORTB = B11100001;
  analogWrite(11, value);
  break;

  case 235:
  // Turn on MOSFETs from pins 9 & 12
  PORTB = B11100001;
  analogWrite(9, value);
  break;

  case 251:
  // Turn on MOSFETs from pins 9 & 13
  PORTB = B11010001;
  analogWrite(9, value);
  break;

  case 243:
  // Turn on MOSFETs from pins 10 & 13
  PORTB = B11010001;
  analogWrite(10, value);
  break;

  case 247:
  // Turn on MOSFETS from pins 10 & 8
  PORTB = B11110000;
  analogWrite(10, value);
  break;
 }
}
```

The only difference between these 2 sections of code is the `analogWrite(pin, 255)` instead of using `digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)`. But if we look in the [source code of the analogWrite function](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c) then it shows that if you plug 255 into `analogWrite(pin, 255)` it will instead run `digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)` This means that these two sections of code in theory should be the exact same. I have not changed anything else in my circuit or code other than this single line for all the phases.

The only difference I can see between these two sections of code would be the runtime because `analogWrite()` function has a few extra lines of code while `digitalWrite()` is slightly quicker.

**Question:**

Does this mean that my Arduino is trying to run code faster than it is capable of running? This seems very unlikely to me because an Arduino Uno is capable of running at 16MHz, but these two sections of code should be the exact same thing other than one of them takes slightly longer. Is there something else that i'm missing here? Does Arduino ever have bugs?

Edit:

Here is my entire code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  DDRB |= B11111111; // Set PORTB pins as OUTPUT pins
  PORTB |= B11110001; // Set pins 13, 12, and 8 to HIGH b/c they are P channel MOSFETs

  DDRD |= B11100011; // Set pins 2, 3, and 4 as INPUT pins for Hall Sensors
  PORTD |= B11111111; // Set pins 2, 3 and 4 as INPUT_PULLUP. 

  PCICR |= B00000100; // Enable interrupts on PORTD
  PCMSK2 |= B00011100; // Specify interrupts on pins 2, 3, and 4. 

}

void loop() {

}

// This function checks for pin Interrupts with Hall Effect Sensors (pins 2, 3, 4). Once an interrupt is detected I switch to the next pair of MOSFETs
// * Note * digital pins 13,12, and 8 are P-CH MOSFETs while digital pins 11,10,9 are N-CH MOSFETs.
ISR(PCINT2_vect) {
   switch(PIND) {
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 11 & 8
    case 231:
    PORTB = B11110000;
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    break;

    case 239:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 11 & 12
    PORTB = B11100001;
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    break;

    case 235:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 9 & 12
    PORTB = B11100001;
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    break;

    case 251:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 9 & 13
    PORTB = B11010001;
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    break;

    case 243:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 10 & 13
    PORTB = B11010001;
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    break;

    case 247:
    // Turns on MOSFETs from pins 10 & 8
    PORTB = B11110000;
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The arduino is controlled by its clock. It fetches an instruction and process it. If the processor stops so does the code. There is no way the code can run without the processor fetching the instructions and executing them.

Comment: @Gil so would the processor stop running if you tried to run it faster than an Arduino can handle? Or would it just slow down to the same speed of the clock? Maybe it would skip lines of code?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using the internal timers in the Arduino system for other parts of your code?  Since the analogWrite instruction is really a PWM function the instruction relies on the internal timers of the controller chip. Changing the operation of the internal timer that is also used for the analogWrite instruction might give unpredictable results.

Comment: neither looks like working code, a motors not going to turn if all the outputs stay high,

Comment: @Jasen i'm using P channel and N channel MOSFETs. So digital pins 13, 12 and 8 are P channel MOSFETs, and digital pins 11, 10, and 9 are N channel MOSFETs. So only 2 MOSFETs are activated at one time.

Comment: 13 12 and 8 ?  what is 10 11 and 9,  what is PORTD= ... ?

Comment: @Nedd that's a good point, but I don't think any of my code is messing with the internal timers. I have included my entire code up above.

Comment: when does 10,11,9 get LOW ?

Comment: PORTD has my 3 hall effect sensor wires. pin 2, 3, and 4 are my hall effect sensors. All the other pins have nothing in them so I set them as outputs.

Comment: what does 
PORTB=... do ?

Comment: The AVR based Arduinos don't really have ability to debug (other than doing things like printing to the virtual serial port, which is not very useful here). Maybe you can drive a spare pin high when you enter the ISR and clear it before you return. With an oscilloscope that will give you some idea of the proportion of available cycles your program spends in the ISR.

Comment: `if you tried to run it faster than an Arduino can handle` ... how could you possibly do that?

Comment: @jsotola The whole program is an ISR so if the ISR does not exit before the next one comes along something undesirable will happen (probably just miss the interrupt). If OP had enabled nested interrupts then other unpleasant things could happen.

Comment: The only way that it could be running faster than it can handle is if you increase the frequency of it's clock crystal. Since you haven't done that, then the code is running at the same speed in both cases.

Comment: When you're writing interrupt handlers you need to be conscious of how long that interrupt handler code takes to execute, which is a function of how many processor instructions your code compiles to. An `analogWrite` 'costs' more than a `digitalWrite`, and using a variable (`value`) 'costs' more than using a constant (`HIGH`).

Comment: Look at the assembler code of your compiled `ISR(PCINT2_vect)` function and count how many instructions it takes (don't just count all the instructions in the function because only one `case` will actually be executed). Then look at your instruction clock and work out how long it'll take to execute all those instructions. Compare that time period to how often the interrupt gets triggered. You may find that the code you've written simply takes to long to execute, leaving you with options like use a faster micro', write better code, and/ or abandon Arduino and go 'bare metal'.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @brhans! I was having trouble getting the Assembly code for almost 2 days now and I finally figured it out for anyone who is curious. Here is a post I made about it if you have macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73940587/how-do-you-get-the-assembly-code-for-a-program-in-the-arduino-ide-macos